# IE only element in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a way that I can create an IE only element in CSS?

I need for the margin to be different in IE compared with other browsers. How can I do this within the actual stylesheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) (As @GOD said, found it with Google in 220ms. Google is your friend.)

**Target ALL VERSIONS of IE**

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target everything EXCEPT IE**

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 5 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie5.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 5.5 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 5.5000]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie55.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 8 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 5.5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 8 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with what @Adrien Lacroix said, this is what you need

```
.element{
    background: gray; /* standard */

    background: pink\9; /* IE 8 and below */

    *background: green; /* IE 7 and below */

    _background: blue; /* IE 6 */
}
```

There is also these if you need them

## IE6 ONLY

```
* html #div { 
    height: 300px;
}
```

## IE-7 ONLY

```
*+html #div { 
    height: 300px;
}
```

## IE-8 ONLY

```
#div {
  height: 300px\0/;
}
```

## IE-7 & IE-8

```
#div {
  height: 300px\9;
}
```

## NON IE-7 ONLY:

```
#div {
   _height: 300px;
}
```

## Hide from IE 6 and LOWER:

```
#div {
   height/**/: 300px;
}
```

## OR

```
html > body #div {
      height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do it.

- IE-only stylesheet

  `<!--[if IE]>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css"/>
  <![endif]-->`
- Javascript - check User Agent and apply necessary styles if IE found - best would be jQuery. Alternatively, you can try [this](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/).